# Page showing extra whitespace without any element after body content

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress [website](http://rubiksoftwares.com/carpark/) build using a free theme, The site showing extra white space without any extra elements. The whitespace shows outside body and html tags.

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't know how to explain my trouble. That is why I am added a website link and screenshot. There are no more words to explain.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  **IMAGES of code are not acceptable.**

Comment: hi you can handle this css #page { position: relative; width: 100%;overflow: hidden;} this will work to remove extra space at bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your submenu: `#primary-menu .sub-menu`. It have css rule `position: absolute;` and because it has `left: -9999px;` and `opacity: 0;` rules, it's a bit hard to detect bug.

The css rule in your theme used as `.main-navigation ul ul`. This may help you to find it faster.